The laravel-vue spa project with the sbadmin 2 template cannot display api data when reloaded
My project with laravel-vue spa and the sb admin 2 template cannot display api data from the postgre database when the localhost:8000/admin/monitoring page is reloaded, please help:
Kode monitoring.vue
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="satker">Pilih Perangkat Daerah</label>
            <select id="satker" class="form-control" v-model="selectedSatker" @change="handleSatkerChange()">
              <option v-for="satker in satkers" :key="satker.id" :value="satker.namasatker">{{ satker.namasatker }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "monitoring",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedSatker: '',
      satkers: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const cachedData = localStorage.getItem('satkers');
    if (cachedData) {
      this.satkers = JSON.parse(cachedData);
    } else {
      this.fetchSatkers();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchSatkers() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/satker');
    this.satkers = response.data;
    localStorage.setItem('satkers', JSON.stringify(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    // Tambahkan penanganan kesalahan di sini, misalnya notifikasi kepada pengguna atau tindakan lainnya
  }
},
    handleSatkerChange() {
      console.log('Selected value:', this.selectedSatker);
    }
  }
};
</script>

api.php
Route::post('login', [Api\AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('register', [Api\RegisterController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('forgot', [Api\ForgotController::class, 'forgot']);
Route::post('reset', [Api\ForgotController::class, 'reset']);
Route::get('email/resend/{user}', [Api\VerifyController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', [Api\VerifyController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');; // Make sure to keep this as your route name

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::get('user', [Api\AuthController::class, 'user']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest:api'], function () {
    Route::get('/satker', 'App\Http\Controllers\Category@satker');
});`

data remains loaded when the monitoring menu page is reloaded,
but the code above when in incognito browser is normal

What does console says? Any errors? Does it send a request again after reloading? If not, look, how parsed data looks like. For me it looks, like your parsed data cannot be read/processed by frontend.
